# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable error while trying to calculate from a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
def calculate_xyz(df,input_df,row):
    if df['Indicator'].eq('Ad').all(axis=None):
      input_df=input_df.filter(like='Ad').iloc[0].astype(float)
      return ((df['a']*input_df['Ade']["Metric_P"+str(row)])+
              (df['b']*input_df['Adf']["Metric_P"+str(row)])+
              (df['d']*input_df['Adg']["Metric_P"+str(row)])).mul(100)
    elif df['Indicator'].eq('Dir').all(axis=None):
      input_df=input_df.filter(like='Dir').iloc[0].astype(float)
      return ((df['a']*input_df['Dire']["Metric_P"+str(row)])+
              (df['b']*input_df['Dirf']["Metric_P"+str(row)])+
              (df['d']*input_df['Dirg']["Metric_P"+str(row)])).mul(100)
              
#dataframe input_df:           
 
 Input      Ade      Adf     Adg    Dire     Dirf    Dirg
Metric_P1   0.0511  -0.0222 -0.0138 0.0511  -0.0222 -0.0138
Metric_P2   0.0511  -0.0222 -0.0138 0.0511  -0.0222 -0.0138
Metric_P3   0.0511  -0.0222 -0.0138 0.0511  -0.0222 -0.0138 
Metric_P4   0.0511  -0.0328 -0.0138 0.0511  -0.0328 -0.0138
Metric_P5   0.0511  -0.0328 -0.0138 0.0511  -0.0328 -0.0138 
Metric_P6   0.0511  -0.0328 -0.0138 0.0511  -0.0328 -0.0138 
Metric_P7   0.0511  -0.0306 -0.0138 0.0511  -0.0306 -0.0138
Metric_P8   0.0511  -0.0306 -0.0138 0.0511  -0.0306 -0.0138


for i in range(1,len(lift_ade_dict)+1):
lift_ade_dict["lift_Ade_P"+str(i)]=lift_ade_dict["lift_Ade_P"+str(i)].assign(Col1=calculate_xyz(lift_ade_dict["lift_Ade_P"+str(i)],input_df,i))
lift_dire_dict["lift_Dire_P"+str(i)]=lift_dire_dict["lift_Dire_P"+str(i)].assign(Col1=calculate_xyz(lift_dire_dict["lift_Dire_P"+str(i)],input_df,i))
```

Both `lift_ade_dict`,`lift_dire_dict` are dictionaries of dataframes.
Keys are like lift_Ade_P1,lift_ade_P2,lift_Ade_P3 for lift_ade_dict and lift_Dire_P1,lift_Dire_P2 for lift_dire_dict.
I am trying to multiply corresponding Metric_P value of input_df for columns ade,adf,adg with the lift_ade_dict and for columns Dire,Dirf,Dirg with the lift_dire_dict.

I am getting the following error :-
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: When do you get that erroe? What code line?

Comment: while running the for loop `lift_ade_dict["lift_Ade_P"+str(i)]=lift_ade_dict["lift_Ade_P"+str(i)].assign(Col1=calculate_xyz(lift_ade_dict["lift_Ade_P"+str(i)],input_df,i))`

Comment: Hmm. Well your index error means, that somewhere in the code your are trying to index a scalar value, i.e., `x[i]`, where `x` is a scalar value (e.g. integer). I have a hard time imagining what's in each variable in your function `calculate_xyz`. So maybe print out all the parameters and also `input_df` after you changed it and break down the steps of accessing it.